# Changes in esri config in VS2010 has no effect

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#

I've created a DockableWindow in my Add-In (vs 2010, c#, arcobjects 10 sp2) and the esri config was updated with the following:

```
<DockableWindows>
    <DockableWindow id="CTArcMapAddin_AreasDockWindow" class="AreasDockWindow+AreasDockWindowImpl" caption="Areas" image="Images\AreasDockWindow.png">
      <InitialPlacement height="300" width="250" state="unpinned" position="left" />
    </DockableWindow>
  </DockableWindows>
```

I run the Add-In and the dockable window shows up on the left side...

Then when changing the "position" value to "right" and running the addin again it's still positioned to the left...why does that change not show through...a bug maybe?

Comment: Are you restarting ArcMap between the builds? If I'm not mistaken, you have to shutdown and restart ArcMap between the builds so it takes the changes.

Comment: @Chad: Yes restarting between builds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my machine when arcmap shuts down it writes dockable window locations to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\DockingPaneLayouts\panestate\Pane-XX`  where XX is some sequence number.

I don't see an easy way to find the registry path without iterating through all the subfolders under panestate.  Once you find it though, I suppose you could clear it so it doesn't override the positions in your config file.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, I suppose I could do that...still think it's a bug tho...

Comment: I think Esri would need an attribute on the DockableWindow element in the config, something like `overrideregistry=true`.  There are probably some users who want the dockablewindow to remain where they placed it the last time they used arcmap.